# Verify Spock mock asynchonous interaction after an exception is thrown

Tags: java, asynchronous, spock

I am trying to use a Blocking Variable to verify an asynchonous interaction after a collaborator's method fails.
This is what I got:

```java
public class ServiceAImpl {
    private final ServiceB serviceB;
    private final ServiceC serviceC;

    @Override
    public void createAccount(String userId) {
        try {
            serviceB.createUserAccount(userId);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            asyncSaveCreationError(e);
            throw e;
        }
    }

    private void asyncSaveCreationError(Exception e) {
        runAsync(() -> saveCreationError(e));
    }

    private void saveCreationError(Exception e) {
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
        PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);
        e.printStackTrace(pw);

        serviceC.save(pw.toString());
    }
}
```

```java
class ServiceAImplTest extends Specification {
    def serviceB = Mock(ServiceB)
    def serviceC = Mock(ServiceC)

    @Subject
    def subject = new ServiceAImpl(serviceB, serviceC)

    def "createAccount - should throw Exception and save error"() {
        given:
        def result = new BlockingVariable<Boolean>(10)

        when:
        subject.createAccount("userId")

        then:
        1 * serviceB.createUserAccount(_) >> { throw new Exception() }
        thrown(Exception)
        1 * serviceC.save(_) >> { result.set(true) }
        result.get()
        0 * _
    }
}
```

Exception is thrown, but the blocking variable is never set so I'm getting the following error:

```
BlockingVariable.get() timed out after 10.00 seconds
    at spock.util.concurrent.BlockingVariable.get(BlockingVariable.java:113)*
```

I tried to use a plain Thread.sleep but always failed the interaction of `serviceC.save`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing that breaks you code, is that mock interactions are the first thing that is evaluated in every `then` block, even if you list other things first. So for it to work, you need to use a second `then` block as explained in the chapter [invocation order](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_invocation_order_2) in the docs. Since, the mocks are evaluated first, the execution doesn't even reach `result.get()` that would wait long enough so that the save interaction could be triggered.

This should fix your problem:

```
class ServiceAImplTest extends Specification {

    ServiceB serviceB = Mock()
    ServiceC serviceC = Mock()

    @Subject
    def subject = new ServiceAImpl(serviceB, serviceC)

    def "createAccount - should throw Exception and save error"() {
        given:
        def result = new BlockingVariable<Boolean>(10.0)
        
        when:
        subject.createAccount("userId")
        

        then: 'first catch the exception and wait for the result'
        thrown(Exception)
        result.get()
        
        then: 'verify mock interactions'
        1 * serviceB.createUserAccount(_) >> { throw new Exception() }
        1 * serviceC.save(_) >> { result.set(true) }
        0 * _
    }
}
```

You can test the MCVE on the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?codez=eJx9VM9v2jAUPi9_hcXJqTaLXseGVqIeeqg0CbYdK-M8wG2wLdtJiir-9zlOnDgE6gOK_d73vZ8f_Kiktsgoyd5IaXlBmBSs1BqEJXcJb817LWV1IlZTYXZSH50l4cKC3lEGaA264gxW6CP5ksMOMQ3Uwh8D-oExWQqL11ZzsUele-J5mpyvoDOHRu40BIZWEDCgtdQeosptwRliBTUmoB6ejqpwSA9Vmlcu8JCP6T4WV-1ZsGcLb_Y_MS-eEH2dYtMu7-bYAzck-KKfPeyqQzY4ZN7hnAxpdLVWkuddO6-08ikfBden6NacEJ5MB9LBF73_GTFq2QHhx3cGynIpEKQXfNScBFu72WQNn3N5bGaDIaJpi9SyRhBxx-WFIfjSbjDeyKH_2Byce06MpW43P_y6XKb0SdCp-414bav_ae5WFZnazUtAPXrFUem_3bPtnFVwjh6xqSNvIKoxrS1lbxvtdIBVY-7tYTOI14KqiZVtYJx2LOdGE1MxbMBYBO8WRO4MChjfceZrDTKZbLXL9dnJH6exedjwweztv9bl9hWYHdTa3kN7YgENuunlkvS42Wix0TdkDrIs8m5_hplQ0c6s_SuY4XhEe16B-N5fG1oNpixCNqvCZe669pdqTrcF_FhJWQAVS3w_J_N0ulr1IebrSiNjCc5a9cwieKTwGO9LEcN-DYg2S7IHi69kMWa5R3efafklRculk0Hbt6bqPh4OOrig6dYqILtkjEvG6hJi0NyBXoZ9Gwn9P6a14HM)

Comment: This is super tricky to wrap one's head around and would be worth a separate example in that same manual chapter, maybe also mentioned in the small paragraph dealing with [polling conditions](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_polling_conditions), async conditions and blocking variables (which also could use some expanding, BTW). The potential of those helper classes for asynchronous code is significant, so it would be helpful to deal with them in some more detail. I am sure there are existing tests which could be embedded into the docs.

Comment: Actually, `BlockingVariable` is made entirely redundant by `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Maybe, that should be documented and deprecated and the former made a facade for the latter, if it is not implemented like that yet. I did not check, actually.